# My code does not respond to print command

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def factorial(x = input("type here: ")):
  total = 1
  while x>0:
    total *= x
    x -= 1
  return total
  print factorial(x)
```

**What I am trying is find factorial of a number, but my code does not respond to print command. After input of a number and pressing enter nothing happen. What is wrong here?**

Comment: @snakecharmerb I did but it says: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: Nothing is executed after `return`,  move it one line up.

Comment: put the input() call before the print and not inside the function prototype and fix the indentation as snakecharmerb already told you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  You need to have the print statement outside the function definition, and also the assignment of `x`.

```
    def factorial(x):
      total = 1
      while x>0:
        total *= x
        x -= 1
      return total

    n = input("type here: ")
    print factorial(n)
```

Comment: _Note that the return value of input is a string_ - it's Python 2, so it's `int`.

Answer (score -1):

you adopted a recursive method to find a fictoral. Your code is erroneous following code will work.

def factorial(x):

```
  total =1
  while x>0:
        total =total * factorial (x-1)

  return total
```

n = input("type here: ")

print factorial(n)